# Svelte component in keyed if/else block not dismounted/removed from dom and piles up

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In the app I'm building with Svelte-kit I'm encountering a problem that I'm not sure is a bug. Consider the following code, it's a makeshift router so to speak, in which a single +page.svelte serves up one of the four possible views.

```
{#key $view}
<div in:fade={{ duration: 200 }} class="page {$view}">
   {#if $view === 'spellbook'}
      <Spellbook />
   {:else if $view === 'library'}
      <Library />
   {:else if $view === 'browse'}
      <Browse />
   {:else if $view === 'settings'}
      <Settings />
   {/if}
</div>
{/key}
```

However, the `<Spellbook />` component is never removed from the DOM and keep piling up when returning to the 'spellbook view'. The other views correctly dismount when the $view variable changes. This all results in the contents of the page div being cluttered by the contents of the `<Spellbook />` component. Apart from this possibly not being the expected behavior I'm also just very confused why this is happening. Below is a screenshot of the live HTML structure, displaying how the spellbook component is duplicated multiple times.

[image]

The full project can be found https://github.com/grabbels/spellbook-pro-app/, the Spellbook component can be found in src/views.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem, or at least I was able to solve it, I'm just not sure it solved the underlying problem which might be a bug.

The spellbook.svelte view uses a component in an each block generated from an array. This component (spellcard) has a fade transition on it. Removing this transition fixed the issue. However, I'm not sure why a nested component having a transition should break the dom in such a profound way.

Comment: Same happened with me. In my case, sveltekit was telling that the component not found, even when it wasn't supposed to by rendered (if statements). I was banging my head. Thanks to your post, tried removing transitions and it works flawlessly now. Transitions are weirid.